# Delayed job for pdfkit middlware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit middleware on Heroku to generate pdf. How can i make pdf generating thing as a background job.

```
def index

    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf 
    end  

end
```

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+background+jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so simple what the other answers are suggesting in fact.

Implementing delayed job for PDF generation is all well and good. But you have more things to consider -  you pass the process over to DJ and the end result is a PDF is generated. But you have to then get that PDF back infront of the user - either by polling the job for when it completes and then providing a link to the pdf possibly, or sending them an email to collect the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

try [HireFire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) The Heroku Worker Manager. it will use Delayed Job and Resque workers on Heroku